# this.props object in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking at this [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js) of this [async](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) example. I want to know the `this.props` object. so I add debugger in the code, and I can see it looks like this.

[image]

my question is, why it contains these fields? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Redux, the `props` are prepared and passed to the component through `connect` function ([connect documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

It accepts arguments:

> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])

`mapStateToProps` is the function to map "state from the store" to the "props used by the component".

This function accepts the `state` of the redux store as the parameter, process/filter them, and return an object:

```
  return {
    selectedReddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
```

That will be passed to the component.

The remaining value `dispatch` is injected by default:

> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, ... If you omit it, the default implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

Reference: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

The function `dispatch` is used to dispatch an [action](http://redux.js.org/docs/Glossary.html#action) (returned by some [`action creator`](http://redux.js.org/docs/Glossary.html#action-creator)). `dispatching` an action will trigger Redux to re-evaluate the store, pass the store value to the react DOM tree from top to down, and re-render the components if needed.

Reference: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch